# $resource returns an empty object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular-resource

I use a $resource to get data from the Server calling an ASP.NET MVC controller from my angular controller. The value (of type decimal?) is correctly returned from the MVC Controller, but when the promise is resolved, its parameter is just an empty object and not the expected value.

**$resource file**:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .service('datacontext', function ($rootScope, $resource) {

    return {
            emissions: $resource('/api/emissions/:id', { 'id': '@id', emissionId: '@emissionId' },
            {                    
                create: { method: 'POST' },
                lock: { method: 'PUT', url: "/api/emissions/lock" },
                getFxRate: { method: 'GET', isArray: false, url: '/api/emissions/getfxrate'}
            })
     }
```

**ASP.NET MVC Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/emissions/getfxrate")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFxRate(string currency)
{
     var res = await _emissionsAppService.GetFxRateAsync(currency);

     //Here I get properly a decimal value as expected. (eg. 1.07123)
     return Ok(res);
}
```

**Angular Controller**:

```
 function getRate(currency){
  datacontext.emissions.getFxRate({ currency: currency})
    .$promise.then(function (result) {

         //Here result is just an empty object {}
    }
  }
```

I cannot understand what is missing to get back the value form the server to the client controller.

Answer (score 0):

The resolved promise was empty as a JSON object is expected, while I was returning a primitive value.

I could fix it by adding the following code to my $resource. As soon as I was returning an object, I could grab the value correctly inside the promise:

```
getFxRate: {
     method: 'GET',
     isArray: false,
     url: '/api/emissions/getfxrate',
     transformResponse: function (data) {
             return { fxRate: data };
         }
    }
```